# Increment and decrement issue in Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-provider

I am having some issues in my code.

I am trying to create a product cart where a user clicks on the + button to increase the quantity of products and clicks on - button to decrease the quantity of products. Also these products are recommended products so they should have a default quantity of 1 product. But when I set the initial quantity to be 1, it does not behave well. When I click on the product once, it does not update but when when I click the second time, it updates it to 2.

I tried doing some print statement, and I noticed that the default is still 0 and when it is clicked once, it just update to 1 and the second time is now 2 which now changed on the UI. How do I make it know there is an existing item of 1 quantity so when I increase it, it changes to 2 immediately. Also when I decrease it, it changes to 0 since it is 1 by default.

These are my code I am using provider for state management.

//cart_provider.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/product_model.dart';

class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> cartItems = [];

  void addProduct(Product product) {
    final existingProductIndex =
        cartItems.indexWhere((p) => p.productName == product.productName);
    if (existingProductIndex != -1) {
      cartItems[existingProductIndex].quantity++;
    } else {
      product.quantity = 0;
      cartItems.add(product);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateQuantity(Product product, bool isIncrement) {
    final existingProductIndex =
        cartItems.indexWhere((p) => p.productId == product.productId);
    if (existingProductIndex != -1) {
      if (isIncrement && product.quantity < 99) {
        cartItems[existingProductIndex].quantity++;
        product.isDecrementButtonDisabled = false;
      } else if (!isIncrement) {
        cartItems[existingProductIndex].quantity--;
        if (cartItems[existingProductIndex].quantity == 0) {
          product.isDecrementButtonDisabled = true;
        }
      }
    } else {
      addProduct(product);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

//product_card.dart (this is where I am displaying the data"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:greenbii_app/providers/cart_provider.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../constants/constants.dart';
import '../models/product_model.dart';

class ProductCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;

  const ProductCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.currency(
      locale: 'en_NG',
      name: 'naira',
      symbol: '₦',
    );
    return Consumer<CartProvider>(
      builder: (context, cartProvider, child) {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    product.productName,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.textColor,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    product.descriptions,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.disabledColor,
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Text(
                    currencyFormat.format(double.parse(product.amount)),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: product.isDecrementButtonDisabled
                      ? null
                      : () => context
                          .read<CartProvider>()
                          .updateQuantity(product, false),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Text(product.quantity.toString()),
                const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => context
                      .read<CartProvider>()
                      .updateQuantity(product, true),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

//product_model.dart

```
class Product {
  final int productId;
  final String productName;
  final String descriptions;
  final String amount;
  bool isDecrementButtonDisabled = false;
  int quantity = 1;

  Product({
    required this.productId,
    required this.productName,
    required this.descriptions,
    required this.amount,
  });

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Product &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          productId == other.productId;

  @override
  int get hashCode => productId.hashCode;
}
```

//loan_application.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:greenbii_app/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:greenbii_app/providers/cart_provider.dart';
import 'package:greenbii_app/widgets/menu_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../models/product_model.dart';
import '../navigations/navigate.dart';
import '../widgets/data/product_data.dart';
import '../widgets/product_card.dart';

class LoanApplication extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoanApplication({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoanApplication> createState() => _LoanApplicationState();
}

class _LoanApplicationState extends State<LoanApplication> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const MenuAppBar(
        menuName: 'Loan Application',
        isBack: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColors.successColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Best rate! The Purchasing Power Index of your business has been applied to your interest rate.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              const Text(
                'Recommended Devices',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 31.0, horizontal: 21.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColors.whiteColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  boxShadow: const [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: AppColors.shadowColor,
                      spreadRadius: 0.0,
                      blurRadius: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: products.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final product = products[index];
                    // final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
                    return Consumer<CartProvider>(
                        builder: (context, cartProvider, child) {
                      return ProductCard(
                        key: ValueKey(product.productId),
                        product: product,
                      );
                    });
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
                    height: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const Text(
                'More Devices',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 31.0, horizontal: 21.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColors.whiteColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  boxShadow: const [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: AppColors.shadowColor,
                      spreadRadius: 0.0,
                      blurRadius: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: products.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final product = products[index];
                    final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
                    return ProductCard(
                      key: ValueKey(product.productId),
                      product: product,
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
                    height: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // navigate(context, const LoanApplication());
          },
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              color: AppColors.primaryColor,
            ),
            child: const Text(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              'Apply for Funding',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

//product_data.dart

```
import 'package:greenbii_app/models/product_model.dart';

final List<Product> products = [
  Product(
    productId: 1,
    productName: 'Mobile Tablet',
    descriptions: '10 inches screen, 4g ram, table or wall fitted.',
    amount: '100000.00',
  ),
  Product(
    productId: 2,
    productName: 'Laptop',
    descriptions: '(500GB HDD, 8GB RAM, Core i5).',
    amount: '250000.00',
  ),
  Product(
    productId: 3,
    productName: '2.5Kva Backup Solar',
    descriptions: '24v hybrid inverter, 2 batteries, 4 380W panels.',
    amount: '300000.00',
  ),
];
```

I am a beginner Flutter developer.

Comment: In `addProduct`, in the `else` branch, you set `product.quantity = 0;`, shouldn't it be `1`?

Comment: When I set it to 1, it still doesn't behave properly. It sees it as 1 product and still need me to click twice to make it work

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that at the very first increment to any product, you're not actually having that product yet in `cartItems`. The product is being read directly from the `products` list, so the first increment only add the product to the `cartItems`, without incrementing it. Since you said that these products should have the initial quantity to 1, it means that you should populate `cartItems` with products from the `products` list at the very beginning. You can solve it by changing the initialization of `cartItems` like this:

```dart
class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> cartItems = [...products];

  // ...
}
```

Comment: This woks too. I have been able to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

So I have been able o sort this. I realised that I am not fetching the products into the cart and also not allowing the state management to handle the state.